# how to stop TappedEvent when DoubleTappedEvent is fired in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a Stackpanel with tapped and doubleTapped Event.

```
        StackPanel ButtonPanel=new StackPanel{Widyh=100,Height=30};
        ButtonPanel.IsDoubleTapEnabled = true;
        ButtonPanel.DoubleTapped += ButtonPanel_DoubleTapped;
        ButtonPanel.Tapped += ButtonPanel_Tapped;

        private void ButtonPanel_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        Debug.WriteLine("Tapped");
        }

        private void ButtonPanel_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        Debug.WriteLine("Double");
        }
```

When I double tap on Stackpanel,it fires tapped event first and then doubleTapped event.In this case,I Don't want to fire tapped event . How to stop firing tappedEvent when double tapped?.I want to do separate actions for tapped and doubeTapped Event. How to do it in UWP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.tapped?view=winrt-19041#remarks) mentions that ”If you want different logic for Tapped versus DoubleTapped, your Tapped handler may need to use app-specific variables and a timer in order to avoid running on interactions that are eventually interpreted as a DoubleTap action.”

So you could solve this issue like the following.

```
    public bool singleTap;  
    private async void ButtonPanel_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        singleTap = true;
        await Task.Delay(200);
        if (this.singleTap)
        {
         
            Debug.WriteLine("Tapped");
        }
            
    }

    private void ButtonPanel_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        singleTap = false;
        Debug.WriteLine("Double");
    }
```